# This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times

Tags: codeigniter, session, redirect

Whenever enable this code

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_id'))
{
return redirect('welcome/index');

}
```

getting an error like
This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: the code does what you wrote: no session-> redirect, no session->redirect, etc, etc...

Comment: try this `if(empty($this->session->userdata['user_id'])){`